# Кто может оценить небольшой проект на react router?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Написал небольшую программу для фильтра и вывода содержимого на react redux.Кто может подсказать , как сделать лучше или показать пример решения подобной задачи ?

ссылка на страницу - https://quintis1212.github.io/react-redux-project/build/index.html

Код :

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Reducer} from './redux/reducer';
import Actions from './redux/actions';
import Filtered from './redux/Filtered';
import {store} from './redux/reducer';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data:store.getState()
  }
  render () {
    store.subscribe(() => {
      this.setState({
        data:store.getState()
      })
    })

    return (

        <div className="App">

         <Reducer/>
         <Actions obj={this.state.data}/>
        <Filtered obj={this.state.data}/>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;


//reducer.js

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import React from 'react'

let obj = {
    state:[
        {
            model: "bmv",
            year: 2000,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          },
          {
            model: "bmv",
            year: 2001,
            typeFuel: "benzin"
          },
          {
            model: "bmv",
            year: 2003,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          },
          {
            model: "bmv",
            year: 2006,
            typeFuel: "benzin"
          },
          {
            model: "bmv",
            year: 1980,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          },
          {
            model: "bmv",
            year: 1999,
            typeFuel: "benzin"
          },
          {
            model: "audi",
            year: 2001,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          },
          {
            model: "audi",
            year: 2003,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          },
          {
            model: "audi",
            year: 2007,
            typeFuel: "benzin"
          },
          {
            model: "audi",
            year: 1989,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          },
          {
            model: "audi",
            year: 1989,
            typeFuel: "benzin"
          },
          {
            model: "audi",
            year: 1993,
            typeFuel: "diesel"
          }
    ],
    newObj:[]
}

  ;



function counter(state = obj, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'FILTER-ACTION':
          const {model, year, typeFuel} = action
          console.log(action)
             function filter(model, year, type) {
              return  state.state.filter(el => {
                    return el.model === model;
                  }).filter(el => {
                    return el.year < year;
                  }).filter(el => {
                    return el.typeFuel === type;
                  });


              }
              let newObj = filter(model, year, typeFuel)

             return state = {
                 state:state.state,
                 newObj:newObj
             }
      case 'SEE-ALL-CARS':
        console.log(state = {
          state:state.state,
          newObj:state.state
      })
          return state = {
            state:state.state,
            newObj:state.state
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  let store = createStore(counter)



 function Reducer() {
    return (
        <div>
            232323
        </div>
    )
}


export   {Reducer,store}

//actions.js

import React , {Component} from 'react'
import {store} from './reducer';


function action(){
    return {
        type: 'FILTER-ACTION' ,
        model: 'bmv' ,
        year: 2009,
        typeFuel: 'benzin'
    }
}


store.dispatch(action())



export default class Actions extends Component  {

    state = {
        type: 'FILTER-ACTION' ,
        model: 'bmv' ,
        year: 2009,
        typeFuel: 'benzin'
    }

    handleClick(event){
        let value = event.target.value.split("-")
        let keyForState = value[0].toString()
        let valueForState = value[1]
        this.setState({
        type: 'FILTER-ACTION' ,
        [keyForState]:valueForState
        }, () => {
        store.dispatch(this.state);
        })
   }
   checkHandler(e){
       console.log(e.target.checked)
       if (e.target.checked ) { 
        this.setState({
            type:'SEE-ALL-CARS'
            }, () => {
            store.dispatch(this.state);
            })
       } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
        this.setState({
            type:'FILTER-ACTION'
            }, () => {
            store.dispatch(this.state);
            })
       }

   }



    render () {

        return (

        <div>
        <label >
        click to see all cars :
        <input
        name="see-all-cars"
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(e)=>this.checkHandler(e)} />
        </label>
        <div style={{ display: "block"}}  onChange={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        <div>
            click on model:
            <select >
            <option value="model-bmv">BMV</option>
            <option value="model-audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
            <div>
            click on year of machine:
            <select   >
            <option value="year-2009">2009</option>
            <option value="year-2000">2000</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div>
            click on fuel:
            <select  >
            <option value="typeFuel-benzin">benzin</option>
            <option value="typeFuel-diesel">diesel</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    )
    }

}
//Filtered.js

import React from 'react';







export default function Filtered({obj}) {
console.log(obj)
if ( obj.newObj.length > 0 ){
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>List of filtered obj :</h3>

            { 

                obj.newObj.map((el,i,arr)=>{
                    return (
                        <ul key={i}>
                       <li>Machine model : {el.model}</li>
                       <li>Machine year : {el.year}</li>
                       <li>Machine type of engine : {el.typeFuel}</li>
                       </ul>
                    )})


                    }

        </div>
    ) 

}else {
    return <h4>no match machines , please change search options</h4>
}

    }
```

Comment: Лучший вариант это самоконтроль. Первый пункт - программа должна выполнять поставленную задачу и задумку автора(самого программиста или заказчика) и второй пункт - код должен соответствовать общепризнанным рекомендациям. Для Реакта например https://netology-university.bitbucket.io/codestyle/react/ можно почитать здесь. Гуглится "Рекомендации написания кода {ЯП, Фреймворк и т.д}" . И стоит помнить что не существует идеальной реализации. Всегда можно улучшить, дописать, переписать и оптимизировать. Удачи вам!

Comment: Спасибо Большое )       "Рекомендации написания кода {ЯП, Фреймворк и т.д}" а ЯП это что такое?

Comment: Язык программирования

Comment: Переходите уже на react.хуки, 21 век на дворе